# Access data using ajax in json format from proxy url in shopify

Tags: proxy, shopify

I developed an app and defined a proxy url. I want to get the data from that url in json format in my shopify shop.But it is returning me nothing. If I read in html, It shows me data. Please tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: I get the solution. thanks anyways